# Continue when element is not found in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium

The following script follows a page in Instagram:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver')

# GO INSTAGRAM PAGE FOR LOGIN

browser.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?hl=it')

sleep(2)

# ID AND PASSWORD

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys('test')

elem = browser.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys('passw')

# CLICK BUTTON AND OPEN INSTAGRAM

sleep(5)

good_elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/div/article/div/div[1]/div/form/span/button').click()

sleep(5)

browser.get("https://www.instagram.com")


# GO TO PAGE FOR FOLLOW
browser.get("https://www.instagram.com/iam.ai4/")

sleep(28)

segui = browser.find_element_by_class_name('BY3EC').click()
```

If an element with class `BY3EC` isn't found I want the script to keep working.

Comment: You can't check the status of the element in selenium because find element throws the error when element doesn't exist, but this was efficiently handled in WATIR which sits on the Ruby Selenium Binding where you can simply write ` b.element(id: 'something').exists?` this return true if element exists it return false if element doesn't exist.

Comment: @Rajagopalan That's simply not true... and you are talking about Rudy/WATIR on a question that has nothing to do with Ruby which is not useful. If you have an answer, post it. Comments are for clarifications.

Comment: @JeffC what I am talking is simply true, you can't check the status of the element in selenium when implicit wait is given.

Comment: @Rajagopalan There's no mention in this question of implicit waits so why would you bring that into the discussion? Even if you do use them (see my comment below, it's not recommended), you can turn it off and check.

Comment: @enigmaok Are you still looking for an answer?

Answer (score 2):

When an element is not found it throws `NoSuchElementException`, so you can use `try/except` to avoid that, for example:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    segui = browser.find_element_by_class_name('BY3EC').click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    print('Element BY3EC not found') # or do something else here
```

You can take a look at [selenium exceptions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html) to get an idea of what each one of them is for.

Comment: @enigmaok glad to help, feel free to [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you find it useful :)

Answer (score 1):

surround it with try catches, than you can build a happy path and handle failures as well, so your test case will always work

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to not use Exceptions to control flow. Exceptions should be exceptional... rare and unexpected. The simple way to do this is to get a collection using the locator and then see if the collection is empty. If it is, you know the element doesn't exist.

In the example below we search the page for the element you wanted and check to see that the collection contains an element, if it does... click it.

```
segui = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('BY3EC')
if segui:
    segui[0].click()
```

Comment: Most of the projects use implicit wait so this method doesn't fit well, that's what I said you can't check the status of the element properly in selenium.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I don't think most projects just implicit waits. None of mine ever have and Selenium contributors recommend NOT using implicit waits. Even if you are using implicit waits, you can set the wait time to 0, use the code above, and then set it back to whatever you want.

Comment: That's what we are doing in our selenium project setting to zero, so I find trouble here setting to zero and then restoring the time. That's what I suggest him to use which sits on the top of Ruby Selenium Binding, Kind of Explicit wait is established in it's core, so it wouldn't apply it's waiting behavior when you check the status of the element, it would apply it's waiting behavior when you take an action.